# What are some templates in which the user research results can be presented in a very understandable way?

Tags: user-research

There is the User Persona and Empathy Mapping which presents information about the users in a simple way. But are there any other templates?

I am looking for ways to present user information to Non-UX people.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to present various aspects of your user research. Let's say you have data about **the people** and data about **the tasks**.

---

## Data about people

[image: NNgroup customer journey map]
*(from nngroup [When and How to Create Customer Journey Maps](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/customer-journey-mapping/))*

A **customer journey map** will put the context in which your app will be used.
Airbnb apparently uses a very well designed one in order to make everyone in the company feel involved ([uxpodcast episode 162](http://uxpodcast.com/162-ux-offline-online-katie-dill/)).

You can present it in a more simpler format like a [Customer touchpoints](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/customer-touchpoints-the-point-of-interaction-between-brands-businesses-products-and-customers).

---

## Data about tasks

[image]

*(from the [ICS group](https://www.irit.fr/recherches/ICS/softwares/hamsters/))*

You may have ended it up with a lot of "steps" that a user follows in order to accomplish a given task. The best way to represent such goals for users is to use [Task Modeling](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/task-analysis-a-ux-designer-s-best-friend) as it is visual, yet concise and detailed. It helps communicating on how the users are performing their tasks and in what sequence. I strongly recommend following a HAMSTERS notation (like in the illustration) since it provides a clearer symbology imo.

---

## I want to represent both

[image: Value Proposition Canvas]

*(from [uxdesign.cc](https://uxdesign.cc/how-i-apply-the-value-proposition-canvas-to-convince-my-clients-to-invest-more-time-in-customer-4493845a71aa))*

Sometimes, you do need a very concise way to represent your whole research. You may want to consider a [Value Proposition Canvas](https://www.peterjthomson.com/2013/11/value-proposition-canvas/). It is a great tool for provoking user research by the way.

Finally, let's not forget about the classical [scenarios](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/scenarios.html) in which you can describe high level tasks and provide user insights along.

---

I often refer to the [UX Design Methods & Deliverables](https://uxdesign.cc/ux-design-methods-deliverables-657f54ce3c7d) for a curated list of deliverables and [Methods from usablilty.gov](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/index.html) for grouped methods and their description.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend Customer Journey Maps:
[image: Example of a Customer Journey Map]

Some articles as well:

- [Why/What/When/How to Create a Customer Journey Map](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/customer-journey-mapping/)
- [Several examples of Customer Journey Maps](http://blog.uxeria.com/en/10-most-interesting-examples-of-customer-journey-maps/)